# Can I decode an xpi file using any software for Windows?

Tags: firefox, xpi

The containing .xpi file I have on my pc only displays what appears to be gibberish, like the following below.

=========================================================================

EÙtò¼5d¨Šîx›b5I‡„ŽœpGñ³FBÜ ç±w×ÅjR„dÊøº®Þg¾’Ÿæj(·I®XœPyb-\tè•9³} ð¼¿¿à8HSî¾Œ:sö}êfÆD¤’ã-ÀÃ=mcÀx†Î0 ‡‘ŠÀ@ÄÄ$ÈVã ‚2Bé=ü,èsfrbg+œaù9dT˜¸Â€àü3;48N  ¢¯¨ÿrÛ£pã-\^øœ3ßF4¡:#88;ðÿYð    #³$¨ƒ»Ê (T‘ßÁÃÃE‰üŸÝˆ´±BÚ¸9‰»Ø:ÿCØ~Œ¿âá&ÿ‘ño()ï€Î'õzSñšçolåÑzÉH}r×f÷×=Y>™!ˆš¢Uò%öeŸ'
Jù+à¦^Å W+$òØ6Ø¥å®{CTJJ.ê–
‹µM1(aùUxœ§gh.P)²t+—3½ù"š   enä
¥ÝíVIÔ¾*U],í^':ù5spîéjµx±]øƒ‚õÔJ½É‘7<«µf”†¼[à5U¶eR+ž2ÔÂ€¹)†›K)É‚e‰Øhã³Û™Çð÷CÈ¯9iØ²ŸÐâÑÝØ•¦~É”qì÷Ñ4Á7qå“9yQ‡ più[ª•ê›­M"
°Äo4!ã¡M­®Lú9t?ÂÜÖ®pLWèëb1vDIÓ™¼é ":öäËUxÈwPAM
èeRí¹KSlì‹3
«¬ßrÛÌzURôP1ü–(ãªlmÂÔ«SFäå‹¤Í÷†¯ÑîM‰}ÉÌš“ZzO€tƒ‰û5{â¶AnN¶(›ï»€sR­hR1£äq´õ†öT‡†Rw›XMæ
®X2£ªf¹ÞO%2;dcþ„«i¥‹» 3aÄýò^©|-ž—iÇ»vG—ÓèDý·–Äô9*·™µnt¶y;²`ôvß†Lx²¥ñ

=========================================================================

With that being said, it's an old Mozilla file from an old install which has since been removed and while I'd like to just delete it, I'd also like to try to decipher what it means first.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. To make it clear: you are asking us to **find** a tool for you. That is outside the scope of this community. You could try at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - but be sure to study the policies of that community before putting up a question there. It is bad enough that you just dumped your content here without further thinking "does it fit like this".

Comment: My apologies. No harm intended. I just wanted to know how to decipher this type of programming language and it's usually an added benefit when another program exists just for that purpose. Thank you for keeping me on my toes.

Comment: And it worked. Congratulations.

Comment: Duly noted and happy to oblige. Thank you kindly.

Comment: When things work out : don't forget about accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XPI file is just a ZIP file with a different extension.

Simply rename the file and unzip, or use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to unzip the content (you won't have to rename the file using 7-zip).

The XPI is used to pack extensions for Firefox/Thunderbird and indicates that the content is signed. The content will vary depending on what type the extension is, but it will contain a manifest.json file. Any programming language will be in JavaScript which may reside in root and/or in various folders.